# Destructuring an object's property array value

Tags: typescript

From the typings of an NPM package (discord.js v13.6.0) there are two methods of the `Client` class declared as:

```js
public on<K extends keyof ClientEvents>(event: K, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => Awaitable<void>): this;
```

and

```js
public once<K extends keyof ClientEvents>(event: K, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[K]) => Awaitable<void>): this;
```

I'm trying to implement a class whose constructor calls for one of these functions, based on it's `options` parameter's `unique` property, as follows:

```js
interface EventHandlerOptions<Event extends keyof ClientEvents> {
    client: Client,
    identifier: Event,
    args: ClientEvents[Event],
    enabled?: boolean,
    unique?: boolean,
}

export class EventHandler<Event extends keyof ClientEvents> {
    constructor(options: EventHandlerOptions<Event>) {
        if (options.enabled) {
            options.client[options.unique ? 'once' : 'on'](options.identifier, (...options.args) => {
                console.log(1);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The function call,

```js
options.client[options.unique ? 'once' : 'on'](options.identifier, (...options.args) => {
    console.log(1);
});
```

is prompting me with the following error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(event: Event, listener: (...args: ClientEvents[Event]) => Awaitable<void>): Client<boolean>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(...options: ClientEvents[Event][0], args: ClientEvents[Event][1]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(...args: ClientEvents[Event]) => Awaitable<void>'.
```

I think it has something to do with how `...options.args` is being destructured but I'm not sure why, any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: which npm package is that? It may help people try the example locally?

Comment: It is discord.js v.^13.6.0 @NalinRanjan